# Allow Egress only to internet

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a service sitting on the edge. This service needs to send some stuff somewhere over the Internet.

I'm using Canal CNI.

Can I define a NetworkPolicy that allows egress *only* to the internet, and not the rest of the cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following would work:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: only-allow-internet
spec:
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  # match all pods in the namespace
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
    - to:
        - ipBlock:
            # allow all IPs
            cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
            except:
              # except the private IP ranges: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network
              - 10.0.0.0/8
              - 192.168.0.0/16
              - 172.16.0.0/20
```

It allows all IPs (since every IP matches `0.0.0.0/0`), except the private IP ranges that are defined by the IANA as private IP ranges.

Please note that this will break DNS lookups too, since by default kubernetes pods use the DNS server inside Kubernetes. You can verify it by running the following commands **inside a pod**:

```
$ nslookup google.com
$ nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
```

First one will time out, while second one will work.

By default, Kubernetes DNS IP would be `10.96.0.10`. You can verify it by checking `/etc/resolv.conf` inside a pod. Therefore, if you want DNS lookups to work, you might want to customize the `NetworkPolicy` further, define more specific IP ranges to allow DNS lookups.

Alternatively, you can define the DNS at the pod definition level. Details are here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config

Additionally, instead of blocking all private IP ranges, you can only block the cluster pod/service ranges. You can find them out in the `kube-apiserver` parameters.

Comment: How to allow internet and few other services?