# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy: Allow egress only to internet, and Allow ingress only from ingress controller and promtail

Tags: kubernetes, networking, nginx-ingress, grafana-loki, kubernetes-networkpolicy

By default pods can communicate with each other in Kubernetes, which is unwanted should a pod be compromised. We want to use **NetworkPolicies** to control inbound (ingress) and outbound (egress) traffic to/from pods.

Specifically pods should ONLY be able to:

- Egress: Call services on the internet
- Ingress: Receive requests from the **Nginx-ingress controller**
- Ingress: Send logs via **promtail** to **Loki**

### What I have tried

### 1. Denying all ingress and egress

This is the default policy that we want to gradually open up. It blocks all ingress and egress.

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
```

### 2. Opening egress to internet only

We allow egress only to IP-adresses that are not reserved for **private networks** according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses).

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: egress-allow-internet-only
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 10.0.0.0/8
        - 172.16.0.0/12
        - 192.168.0.0/16
```

### 3. Opening Ingress from ingress controller and loki

We have deployed the standard **NginX Ingress Controller** in namespace **default**, and it has the lable **app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx**. We have also deployed the standard **loki-grafana stack** to the **default** namespace, which uses **promtail** to transfer logs to **Loki**. Here I allow pods to recieve ingress from the **promtail** and **ingress-nginx** pods.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-allow-ingress-controller-and-promptail
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name=default
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name=default
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name=promtail
```

### So, does this configuration look right?

I am new to Kubernetes, so I hope you guys can help point me in the right direction. Does this configuration do what I intent it to do, or have I missed something? E.g. is it enough that I have just blocked **egress** within the **private network** to ensure that the pods are isolated from each other, or should I also make the ingress configuration as I have done here?

Comment: I have compared your Ingress with [K8 Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#allow-all-ingress-traffic) and Egress with this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57845666/19230181)  and [deny Both ingress and Egress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-ingress-and-all-egress-traffic) seems to be correct.The only thing we need to do is check whether all the name space is given correct or not. Seems to be correct as per your YAML file.  Can you verify if you are facing any error?

Comment: The policy "egress-allow-internet-only" seems to block completely for the internet. I have also tried just to write -ipBlock: cidr: 0.0.0.0/0, but I can still not get access to the internet.

Comment: My test is using "curl www.google.com" from one of the containers. I have a hunch that there is a DNS server being blocked.

Comment: kubernetes pods use the DNS server inside Kubernetes due to this DNS server being blocked, we need to define more specific IP ranges to allow DNS lookups. Follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204119/19230181) to define [DNS config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config) at pod levels.

Comment: Even when I allow just 0.0.0.0/0 all egress seems to be blocked. I don't get it.

Comment: Verify by allowing the DNS Lookups by using the above comment.

Comment: Have you verified by allowing DNS Lookups? Is this issue resolved?

Comment: I am just getting started with that. Need to sort out the IP such that I can add it to the egress rule.

Comment: @HemanthKumar It looks like you were right about the DNS. This also means that "0.0.0.0/0" does not open up to ALL ip-adresses, as it does not open up to the DNS pod at "100.64.0.187". I fixed this by adding a namespace selecter (kube-system) and a pod selector (dns pods). Now I can make curl calls with domain names rather than IPs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have compared your Ingress with [K8 Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#allow-all-ingress-traffic) and Egress with this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57845666/19230181)  and [deny Both ingress and Egress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-ingress-and-all-egress-traffic) seems to be correct.The only thing we need to do is check whether all the name space is given correct or not. Seems to be correct as per your YAML file.

But kubernetes pods use the DNS server inside Kubernetes; due to this DNS server being blocked, we need to define more specific IP ranges to allow DNS lookups. Follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204119/19230181) to define [DNS config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config) at pod levels and to get curl calls with domain names allow Egress to Core DNS from kube-system(by adding a namespace selecter (kube-system) and a pod selector (dns pods)).

#### How to identify dns pod

```
# Identifying DNS pod
kubectl get pods -A | grep dns

# Identifying DNS pod label
kubectl describe pods -n kube-system coredns-64cfd66f7-rzgwk
```

### Adding DNS pod to NetworkPolicy

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: egress-allow-internet-only
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 10.0.0.0/8
        - 172.16.0.0/12
        - 192.168.0.0/16
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name: "kube-system"
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: "kube-dns"
```

Comment: I hope it is ok that I expanded your answer with a concrete example that I got working.

Comment: Yes, now it is perfectly complete. Thank you @EsbenEickhardt

Comment: Sure, and thanks for leading me in the right direction. I think I understand it now. The reason why "0.0.0.0/0" does not let you access the DNS pod is that the DNS pod is located in another namespace, thus that has to be specified also.

Comment: Everywhere on the Internet this snippet is incorrect. You must not put that dash before `podSelector`, otherwise you allow connections to ALL pods in `kube-system` namespace and any pod with `k8s-app: kube-dns` label in ANY namespace. That is an example of awful design by k8s dev team, but at least it is described in docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#behavior-of-to-and-from-selectors

Answer (score 2):

For those curious I ended with the following network policy:

```
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: deny-all
  namespace: <K8S_NAMESPACE> 
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-internet
  namespace: <K8S_NAMESPACE>
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  - Ingress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: "0.0.0.0/0"
        except:
        - "10.0.0.0/8"
        - "172.16.0.0/12"
        - "192.168.0.0/16"
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name: "kube-system"
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: "kube-dns"
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-ingress-from-ingresscontroller
  namespace: <K8S_NAMESPACE>
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name: "default"
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: "ingress-nginx"
---
```

It turned out that the DNS server had to be added to **allow-internet** and that it was not necessary to add **allow-ingress-from-promtail**, as promtail gets the log in another way that through ingress.